# Save to db only if changing fields

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a better way of doing the following in Django:

```py
obj = Thing.objects.get(name=name)
if obj.a != a or obj.b != b:
   obj.a = a
   obj.b = b
   obj.save()
```

So I wish to save if either a or b has become invalid and I can’t make any change to the save implementation. And I’d like to stick to using the model instance rather than solving this using a query set.

Could I solve this using update_fields where it is an empty list in the case where I have nothing to save in the db?

Comment: Maybe you could add why provided snippet is not your preferred way of doing it. I suppose just because you're providing a minimal reproducible example it still looks like a neat solution to me. If you know in advance which field has changed you could go for [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) or, in case you need the equality checks, go for by yourself provided `update_fields` approach. But I suppose code would not look much better than right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this counts as *using a queryset*, but you could do this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

object = Thing.objects.filter(name=name).exclude(Q(a=a) & Q(b=b)).first()
if object is not None:
    object.a=a
    object.b=b
    object.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably not a better way tbh.. especially if you only checking if 2 fields were changed, any potential solution would be more lines.

Like, this is usually what I do:

```py
obj = Thing.objects.get(name=name)

requires_save = False

if obj.a != a:
  obj.a = a
  requires_save = True
  
if obj.b != b:
  obj.b = b
  requires_save = True
  
if requires_save:
  obj.save()
```

Now, it's definitely longer by a lot. If this was 4-15+ fields you could probably break up the checking+changing into a function, or even a model method, and by using `getattr()` to make it somewhat dynamic.. but it's really not worth the time for checking 2 fields

Answer (score 0):

This only makes sense if you have multiple fields you need to check.

```py
obj = Thing.objects.get(name=name)
field_names = ["a", "b"]
pot_new_values = [val_a, val_b]
uf = [
    field for field, value in zip(field_names, pot_new_values) if obj.getattr(field) == value
]
obj.save(update_fields=uf)
```

[Further explanation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save): 
An empty list for `update_fields` skips the `.save()`. 
Obviously it is not going to save other fields than those mentioned in `update_fields`.
In `update_fields` mentioned fields will force-updated.